# Adding a blank space in an XML attrib with lxml in Python

Tags: python, html, lxml

```
from lxml import etree

html = etree.Element("html")
body = etree.SubElement(html, "body")
body.text = "TEXT"
body.set("p style", "color:red")
print(etree.tostring(html))
```

Gives me the error: ValueError: Invalid attribute name u'p style'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The following element, which your code is trying to produce, isn't valid XML : `<body p style="color:red">TEXT</body>`. And what does it (the `p stye=".."`) mean anyway in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an attribute with a space in it in XML, which is what `lxml` and `etree` are for. The XML specification states what a valid attribute name is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-Name).

If you are trying to achieve this:

`<html><body p style="color:red">TEXT</body></html>`

You can't do that in XML. You can do something similar in HTML: empty attributes. See [the HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) for details. But you wouldn't use the kind of code written above to get that result.

---

If you are trying to get the following result (which seems more likely):

`<html><body><p style="color:red">TEXT</p></body></html>`

Then it is very easy.

```
from lxml import etree

html = etree.Element("html")
body = etree.SubElement(html, "body")
p = etree.subElement(body, "p")
p.text = "TEXT"
p.set("style", "color:red")
print(etree.tostring(html))
```